# Meteor.user() is undefined when directly access the url

Tags: meteor

I have a url `http://localhost:3000/test` :

```
Template.test.onRendered(function() {
   console.log(Meteor.user());
});
```

If I first open `http://localhost:3000/`, then click the `test` link, `Meteor.user()` will be printed.

But if I directly open `http://localhost:3000/test`(Input the url in Chrome's address bar and hit enter), `Meteor.user()` is undefined.

Why??

Comment: The template gets rendered before Meteor.user() is ready. This is not usually a problem if you use it in a reactive way.

Comment: How to? I add `Meteor.startup(function() {
  if(Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe('userData');
  }
});` to `lib/route.js`, it should loaded at startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Meteor logging in process is not instantaneous upon your app first load, it usually takes a few ms before the user actually gets connected, hence `Meteor.user()` returning `undefined` in your template `onRendered` lifecycle event.

I'm unsure what you're trying to achieve but you can solve this problem by introducing reactivity inside your `onRendered` handler :

```
Template.test.onRendered(function() {
  this.autorun(function(){
    console.log(Meteor.user());
  });
});
```

Declaring a reactive computation using `Tracker.autorun` will allow your code to rerun whenever the value of `Meteor.user()` is updated, and particularly on initial logging in resume process.

Comment: How to use autorun in helper? I need to handle this situation in helpers too.

Comment: Template helpers are already reactive, just use it directly. You'll need to make sure it's not null before you access its properties, though. E.g. `Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().something`.